# Verifying hosted VOIP PBX uptime

Tags: voip, cloud, uptime

For the second time, I'm outsourcing my VOIP hosting to a provider, whom I have to trust their sales pitch of 45 minutes down per 365 days.  Is there an automated way I can test their server(s) without having to make a telephone call every couple hours & log it?  I'm thinking something like a 'ping' would be nice, that I could generate from a Linux script.  Any ideas?

I'll be depending on them for my business, so I don't want to get blindsided by clients who say they can't reach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert why don't you evaluate their solution and monitor it internally during the evaluation period and make your decision based on the results? You could use any of these [tools.](http://www.pernau.at/kd/voip/bookmarks-sip-test.html)

Comment: Nice.  I will try one or more of these tools.

Answer (score 1):

Their server responding to pings is only one small piece of the puzzle. Their equipment and network provider must also work for you to receive calls. If you are receiving their service over the public Internet, then your Internet connection is the most crucial link. Having a quality Internet connection is 70% of the battle. Use this [packet loss and delay test](http://www.hostmycalls.com/tools/) tool to test your Internet.

Comment: Yeah, I've run that test tool at least a dozen times in the last 3 years.  My local ISP is like a rock (which is more than I can say for local electric power).  So weak link in the chain remains the Voip host.